# Is it acceptable to ask what substances are being tested for on a hiring drug test?

Tags: hiring-process, drug-test

I verbally accepted a summer internship offer and expected a urine drug test to be required. However, the official offer states the drug test is a hair test, which goes back roughly three months. I have used THC-containing products a few times over that period, not so much that I wouldn't pass a urine test but enough that I expect to fail a hair test.

My test will probably be within the next month. As a backup plan, I have obtained a medical certification approving my use from my state's department of health (a "green card"). As I understand it, a company could potentially rescind an offer after a positive drug test for THC metabolites, even if the person has medical approval. This could potentially be considered discrimination, and there have been lawsuits over this (clarified in the comments). I believe the case law is still developing (in my state at least) and no outcome is certain. I would rather avoid a complicated legal dispute if possible. All I want to do is work the job I was offered.

A friend of mine pointed out that the employer might not even be testing for THC products. It might be a long shot, but it would certainly help my stress if I knew.

**Edit:** My attempt to provide context may have obscured the question. Feel free to ignore my specific situation and answer the question itself (which may perhaps help others in the future).

**The question:**
*Is it reasonable to ask what substances are being tested for? What's the likelihood of getting an answer, and could trying have any negative repercussions?*

Side question, not the main point:
Additionally, I'd be very appreciative of any insight on whether it would be a better move to mention my green card up front or only in the case of a positive test result.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere OP seemingly wants to reduce stress by knowing that THC products are not being tested for

Comment: Does the company have a presence in states where pot use is still illegal?  Or, does it have federal contracts?  Did they mention in the interview that they do not allow pot use?  (An interview with my company would be a yes to all 3 of those questions.)

Comment: @thursdaysgeek The company is international and is headquartered in another country (but in that country possession of drugs has been decriminalized.) I'm not sure about federal contracts, but I do not think so. This was not discussed in the interview, and I didn't bring it up because I thought it would look unfavorable and I was already prepared to pass a urine test. It may have been naive for me not to ask. I should add this is for a summer internship (but this position may be key for starting my career).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Since you asked, there are lengths one could go to in order to increase chances of passing, but they require significant money and time. If no such costly endeavors are required, it would be helpful for me to know now.

Comment: If the lab is external to the company you may be able to research the type of drug testing that is done, or by calling the lab directly

Comment: If you know the name of the lab, have one of your extroverted friend call the lab or visit in person, and ask questions.

Comment: There is always the shaving option.  They can't go back 3 months if there isn't 3 month's worth of hair growth to select from.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. On the complete shaving option, it's my understanding that if the employee is not "in compliance" with the test then they have not fulfilled the condition of a negative result and their offer would likely be rescinded.

Comment: Also, the most practical "backup plan" is to continue applying and interviewing with other companies (until you get the tests back at the minimum). Don't stop doing that. Don't stop your momentum of looking for a job. Litigation is not a good backup plan. Even successful litigation can take several years to resolve (and honestly, I really doubt that you'd win anything).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk That would be great advice, the issue is that this is a summer internship and the the application window for every company I've seen is now closed. I did actually have another offer, but I declined it after receiving this one, before I knew that there was a hair test.

Comment: @jwh20 they can also take hair from elsewhere on your body (so you better shave *everything*), or nail clippings. Or they could just say "you're clearly trying to cheat the test, goodbye".

Comment: @electronpusher, Ok then. Visualize what would happen if you didn't get the job. Will you work washing dishes in a restaurant? Will you work for a startup? Will you take a backpacking trip through Europe/Asia? I know it sucks, but start thinking about some kind of backup plan. And in the future, never reject other offers until you've actually seen the contract (and the employee manual).

Comment: "This could potentially be considered discrimination, and there have been lawsuits over this." - No, It's not. discrimination at least in the states can only be applied to a protected class.  Taking THC is NOT a recognized protected class.  Just because it's legal in the country where the company is headquartered does not mean they approve of drug use.  *Being compliant with an anti-drug policy is not discrimination.*

Comment: @Donald Thanks for your reply. I think this issue may not be that simple. Here's a relevant case: [Pennsylvania Court: Medical Marijuana Act Allows Employees to Sue for Bias](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/legal-and-compliance/state-and-local-updates/pages/penn-medical-marijuana-act-allows-employees-to-sue.aspx). I hope it goes without saying that I would not be interested doing that.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thanks Stephan. I did my best to be wise, but unfortunately the timing did not work out and this company was not able to provide a written offer before the other company wanted my decision, so I decided to have faith in the verbal offer.

Comment: The details of that are specific, she didn't sue as a protected class, she sued on the grounds that as a state employee the state legislator implicitly indicate she should take it medically by passing the law.  *A state employee in the sense sense she had to be license by the state to do her job.*

Comment: @Donald Ok, here it is then: "No employer may discharge, threaten, refuse to hire or otherwise discriminate or retaliate against an employee regarding an employee's compensation, terms, conditions, location or privileges solely on the basis of such employee's status as an individual who is certified to use medical marijuana." [Section 2103(b)(1)](https://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/legis/LI/uconsCheck.cfm?txtType=HTM&yr=2016&sessInd=0&smthLwInd=0&act=016&chpt=21), Medical Marijuana Act 2016, Pennsylvania General Assembly.

Comment: Are drug tests standard in the US? Is this just another oddity that we Europeans never experience on our side of the pond?

Comment: @fgysin In my experience pre-employment drug tests are quite standard in many (most?) US industries

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can ask, but most of the ways of asking will make it pretty clear that you've taken some drugs and are wondering if they'll show up - especially if you're asking a specific substance. If you pitch the question more as "I've never done one of these tests before, how does it work?" then that's less obvious - but it may not answer your question.

When you take the test, you'll most likely be asked to fill out a form listing all the drugs that you've taken over the last 3+ months (including standard prescription and over-the-counter ones), so you should include it there.

The simplest thing to do is to speak to HR at the company, explain that you use certain products for medical reasons (with approval) which are likely to be flagged on a drugs test, and that it in no way impacts your ability to work/drive/etc. Doing this *before* your drugs test makes you look proactive and open, and means that you have a chance to explain it (which you may not get otherwise - they could just immediately reject you on a positive test result).

If they decide not to hire you on that basis then that sucks, but you've saved everyone time finding dealing with it up front.

Comment: Well, there was a time when they would have found morphine in my blood stream... It helps when two strong men rearrange some broken bones in your leg while you're awake.

Answer (score -1):

Something to keep in mind, depending on the type of job worked, is that there may be a *policy* of conducting this test as part of every job hire and background test, but they may decide to hire you anyway.

Same as, when they run your employment history and can't verify a piece of information, it's not an immediate 'cant hire', it's just another item that gets added to a report and submitted to the hiring manager.

Even if you're positive on THC I would think there's a chance you still get hired. May have some eyes on your performance though

Comment: Thank you. I'm hoping this is a possibility, but I can't see a way to know. Judging from the downvote, apparently someone thinks this is not likely?

Answer (score -3):

If you don't have a contact you can ask. Then just assume they'll test for THC and stop worrying about it.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yeah, my advice is to relieve the stress. I don't give advice on fooling drug tests.

Comment: The question is it not how to fool a drug test, it is whether it is appropriate to ask someone in the company (such as a recruiter) what drugs are tested for, and the likelihood of this yielding useful information and/or repercussions. Neither of the two answers have actually answered this, so perhaps I did not write the question clearly enough. Hopefully it's clear now.